# SonarQube stopped and is not running

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I'm trying to setup SonarQube 7.8 version. Once i start sonar.sh file it is running but after that sonar stops.

```
root@automation:/opt/sonarqube-7.8/bin/linux-x86-64# ./sonar.sh start
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
root@automation:/opt/sonarqube-7.8/bin/linux-x86-64# ./sonar.sh status
SonarQube is not running.
```

I checked the logs and this is what i get:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.10.15 21:01:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube-7.8/temp
2019.10.15 21:01:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.10.15 21:01:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube-7.8/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube-7.8/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.10.15 21:01:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.10.15 21:01:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.10.15 21:01:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.10.15 21:01:41 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.10.15 21:01:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.10.15 21:01:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

es.log file is here :

```
2019.10.15 21:01:41 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
```

I'm not sure why SonarQube stops. Could you help me with that please?

Comment: Are you following some tutorial to setup SonarQube?

Comment: Yes, i'm following this one https://developerinsider.co/install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED:

First, don't run sonarqube as the root user

1. Create user

   command: **useradd username** (put username as sonaradmin(if you don't want to change any command)
2. Create a password command: `passwd username`
3. goto /opt/ directory

3.1) Rename sonarqube.x.x.x to sonarqube command:`sudo mv sonarqube.x.x.x sonarqube`(X.X.X you should change directory name)

4. Change permissions command:`chmod 775 -R sonarqube`(folder name may change Sonarqube )
5. Add Created user to sonaradmin group command: chown -R sonaradmin:sonaradmin sonarqube
6. goto : cd /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/
7. Command:  su sonaradmin
8. Enter password
9. command:`./sonar.sh start`
10. Command:`./sonar.sh status`

Now goto browser check http://localhost:9000/sonar

Hoping this helps.... I have gone through the same issue,solved

Answer (score 2):

ok, i found the solution. All i had to do is to change `#RUN_AS_USER= in /opt/sonarqube-7.8/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh line 48 to RUN_AS_USER=sonar`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution for me doesn't works, cause console show me this messagge (after edit to sonar.sh file)

> groups: "sonar": no such user
>   chown: utente non valido: "sonar:sonar"
>   su: user sonar does not exist

Answer (score 0):

if **baya prakash reddy**'s answer doesn't work, so you can look at the documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/ where it says that you must ensure that:

> vm.max_map_count is greater than or equal to 524288

yo can set it like this:

> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your sonarQube server has at least 4GB of RAM. I had this issue after installing SonarQube with 1GB of RAM. Running SonarQube as sonar did not resolve the issue. Once I installed on RHL with 4GB RAM, issue was resolved